# When does the javamail MimeMessage status change from unseen to seen?

Tags: jakarta-mail

I need to check whether the message is seen or not when displaying it, in order to do some styling like conditional coloring or bold/normal fonts. But actually it is not clear yet to me how the mailserver with javamail controls this issue using the boolean isSeen value. the question is: On which action does this boolean value change from false to true, should I interfere somewhere here or its a javamail issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using IMAP, it's pretty much up to the IMAP server, but generally it happens when you fetch some content from the message, not just headers.